# HSQLDB Insert statement error through TIBCO BW

Tags: insert, hsqldb, tibco, businessworks

I am trying to execute a tibco bw process activity which inserts record into hsqldb table. while inserting record it is throwing an error; here I am attaching the snapshot of error. Any clue?
Error says -

`BW-JDBC-100014 Job-58000 Error in [Process/Receive Message.process/JDBC Update]
"JDBC error reported: (SQLState = 42501) - java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: HAWKEVENTS"
caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: HAWKEVENTS
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: HAWKEVENTS`

Thanks!
-saurabh

Answer (score 0):

anyways, I found the answer.. one should connect to database wither through runManager or through designer; otherwiese locking problem will arise.

Thanks!